# Making background-image page specific

Tags: html, css, background-image, squarespace

I'm currently using the Squarespace platform for my website, and I am trying to change the background image of my homepage, after searching some forums and viewing the source code of my [website](http://www.MoxieGaming.com) I was told that the id `#collection-51648018e4b0d7daf0a7cece` would work to alter ONLY the homepage, but when the code

```
#collection-51648018e4b0d7daf0a7cece {
  background-image: url('image-location.png');
}
```

is added nothing happens, but by using this code

```
#navigator {
  background-image: url('image-location.png');
}
```

It does change, but applies it ALL of my pages. Does anybody know a work-around for this? I've even submitted a ticket to Squarespace but they were no help at all. Also, please realize that I cannot alter the actual code of the website because it is Squarespace. I can only add custom CSS or inject code into the `<head>` tags

Answer (score 0):

Make the `#navigator` selector specific to the homepage:

```
#collection-51648018e4b0d7daf0a7cece #navigator {
  background-image: url('image-location.png');
}
```

**Edit:** Based on your code, you probably want this:

```
#collection-51648018e4b0d7daf0a7cece #navigator {
  background: #fff url('image-location.png') scroll no-repeat top right;
}
```